# How to give a user KILL rights without using server-level permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to give user "John" rights to KILL without using server level permissions.
I tried to do it by using module signing.
But I am unable to grant server-wide permissions (e.g. Process Admin) to user, that was created from certificate.
(Because it has not login).
This is my code:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.KillSPID
    @SPID INT = NULL
AS
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255) 
SET @cmd = 'KILL ' + LTRIM(STR(@SPID))
EXEC(@cmd)
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE AdmCert
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MyStrongPwd'
    WITH SUBJECT = 'Cert for KILL command',
    EXPIRY_DATE = '01/01/2025'
GO

ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.KillSPID
   BY CERTIFICATE AdmCert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'MyStrongPwd';
GO

CREATE USER Executor FROM CERTIFICATE AdmCert;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.KillSPID TO Executor;
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.KillSPID TO John;
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [processadmin] ADD MEMBER Executor;
GO
---------------------
ERROR:
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Cannot add the server principal 'Executor', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

What should I do?

Thanks to all in advance!

**PS:** I tried to add in procedure "WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER" - don't works for me.

Comment: The error message is descriptive - there is in fact no login (i.e. server principal) called Exectutor. There is a user (i.e. database principal), presumably in master, by that same name. Try creating a login from the cert and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Yes, I've already tried this.
But it doesn't work .. (maybe I misunderstood something?)
What I've done:
1) created a login from the certificate
2) gave it server permission
3) created a user in the DB master from this login
4) granted exec permission to the procedure to this user
5) granted exec permission to the procedure to user "John"

When I call the procedure, it works like no additional permissions exist.
(like only 4) command was issued)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=171810), you can achieve this by granting `ALTER ANY CONNECTION` permissions:

I.e.

```
use master
go
GRANT ALTER ANY CONNECTION TO Executor;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working
(this user doesn't have login)

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Cannot add the server principal 'Executor', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: Do you have a domain account or SQL user called `Executor`?

Comment: No. It is a user:

`CREATE USER Executor FROM CERTIFICATE AdmCert;
GO`

Comment: In my case I specify direct the limited user
GRANT ALTER ANY CONNECTION TO [xxxx]; "xxxx" is username